# Pyjnius, Facebook/Google SDK for Sign in Button with Kivy

Tags: android, python, facebook, kivy, pyjnius

So I have been wondering. Can this be implemented with kivy?

I have seen read [this post in kivy planet](https://kivy.org/planet/2013/08/using-facebook-sdk-with-python-for-android-kivy/) about it, but noticed that the login button was a problem.
The article is from 2013, so I would like to know what is the current situation regarding Facebook and Google SDKs and Kivy integration with Pyjnius.

First of all, i'd like to know how to install the SDKs without android-studio, if possible.
Then, how to propperly integrate them with my app.

Hope someone can shed some light in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

A Facebook/Google sign in can be implemented with Kivy. You do not necessarily have to use the Google or Facebook SDK, there are other auth libraries available in Python.

If you are to use the Facebook/Google SDKs, it is still possible as you can execute any Java code with Pyjnius. Per your question about installing 'SDKs' without Android studio, I'm not sure what you mean, but you may specify dependencies in your Buildozer dependency file.

Comment: Can you point out alternative auth libraries? And maybe that's precisely what I mean with installing 'SDKs'. I am inspired by the code on kivy planet example, where he imports facebook classes through pyjnius. In order to do that, I need to have these SDK installed, right?

Comment: Because this is how facebook sugests adding SDK to an android-studio project:(1)Go to Android Studio>New Project>Minimum SDK.(2)Select "API 15: Android 4.0.3" or higher.(3)In your project, open: your_app>Gradle Scripts>build.gradle.(4)Add the Maven Central Repository to build.gradle before dependencies: `repositories { mavenCentral() }`(5)Add compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' to your build.gradle dependencies.(6)Build your project.
(7)Import Facebook SDK into your app: `import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;`   How to do this with pyjnius?

Comment: @GugaFigueiredo https://kivy.org/planet/2013/08/using-facebook-sdk-with-python-for-android-kivy/

Comment: @jligeza This is the exact same link as in my question. p4a has seed major rewriting since and toolchain has changed, so the solution used there no longer works. If you know how to solve this, please post an answer to the question with the steps

Comment: Hi @GugaFigueiredo did you manage to get a way around this? I am struggling with the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not, the project I was working on died and I moved on to different undertakings.. I hope to pick this up again soon.. but so far, nothing to add here. But you should check kivy's official support channels, people there may be able to help you either find a solution or build one.